# Converting a series of .mat files into one CSV File

Tags: matlab, csv, vector, octave

I hope this makes sense:

I have a series of .mat files that i want to use to train a weka classifier and I need to get these .mat files all into one big .CSV file to do so.

My files each contain an eigenvector which hast around 120 values.

Being brand spanking new to this enviroment, i wrote a simple script to concat all these vectos into one long vector, which doesnt really help me.

```
function c = csv()

for i = 1:99

    if i>9
        fname = strcat('Betas00', int2str(i));
    else
        fname = strcat('Betas000', int2str(i));
    end

    fext = strcat(fname, '.mat');
    //fext

    filename = sprintf("%s", fext);
    load(filename);

    dlmwrite('test.txt', fext, '-append');
    dlmwrite('test.txt', ignmds, '-append');

end
```

Its not pretty, but can someone explain how i can use these basic concepts to do what i want? to get a CSV file which has 99 eigenvectors in it? Please? Pretty Please?

Hope that all makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've done it already, what is left to do?

By the way you may want to replace your if with:

```
fname = strcat('Betas', num2str(i, '%-04.4d'));
```